# Why are changes showing in Visual Studio Code for files such as storage.json, state.vscdb, and data_1?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, config

My son is using Visual Studio Code for a Udemy JavaScript Course, and he is encountering a problem I have never had when I've used VS Code. He keeps getting changes listed in Source Control for files such as storage.json (~/.config/Code), the-real-index (~/.config/Code/Cache/index-dir), data_1 (~/.config/Code/GPUCache), and state.vscdb (~/.config/Code/User/globalStorage). There have been others as well, including Git logs.

I created a .gitignore file and tried the following entries:

```
/config
/.config
~/.config
```

I also ran the following after each .gitignore edit:

```
git rm -r --cached
```

I then re-added, committed and pushed files. We are still getting changes popping up in Source Control for files in the ~/.config/ chain. How do we stop this?

EDIT: If it matters, we are running Visual Studio Code on a Chromebook using the Linux Beta that the Chromebook offers.

Comment: the repo is at `~`? that sounds... peculiar

Comment: I find the file system for Linux Beta on the Chromebook a bit confusing. We have a My Files directory. I'm not sure where that is on the computer. My Files contains three directories - Downloads, Linux Files, and Play Files. The repo is in the Linux Files directory.